# Google ML Batch prediction error: Exception during running the graph: assertion failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I deployed a object detection model in Google ML, **I am able to make online prediction**, but it **FAILS** to make **batch prediction**, with below error in stackdriver logs:

> Exception during running the graph: assertion failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP] [[Node: map/while/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_1/Assert = Assert[T=[DT_STRING], summarize=3, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](map/while/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/is_bmp, map/while/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_1/Assert/data_0)]]

I tried both gcloud command and python api but no luck. The request.json file for Online prediction.

```
{"inputs": {"b64": "/9j/4SurRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACgEPAAIAAAAHAAAAhgEQAAIAAAAFAAAAjgEaAAUAAAABAAAAlAEbAAUAAAABAAAAnAEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAA2gITAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAA7oglAAQAAAABAAAC0gAAAyhYaWFvbWkAAE1.....}}
```

It already b64 encoded. It works fine with online prediction:

```
gcloud ml-engine predict --model object_detector  --version v2 --json-instances request.json
```

BUT for Batch prediction it fails, below are two rows for batch_request.json file

```
{'instances': [{"inputs": {"b64": "/9j/4SurRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACgEPAAIAHAAAAhgEQAAIAAAAFAAAAjgEaAAUAAAABAAAAlAEbAAUAAAABAAAAnAEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAA1AAAApAEyAAIAAAAUA...}}]}
{'instances': [{"inputs": {"b64": "/9j/4SurRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACgEPAAIAAAAAAhgEQAAIAAAAFAAAAjgEaAAUAAAABAAAAlAEbAAUAAAABAAAAnAEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAA1AAAApAEyAAIAAAAUA...}}]}
```

body of python api request made for batch predicton:

```
{'jobId': 'mycloud_machine_object_detector_115252',
'predictionInput': {'dataFormat': 'TEXT',
'inputPaths': 'gs://my-bucket/object-detection/batch_request.json',
'outputPath': 'gs://my-bucket/object-detection/',
'region': 'us-central1',
'versionName': 'projects/mycloud_machine/models/object_detector/versions/v2'}}
```

I used the python code from Google Docs for making batch request.

```
project_id = 'projects/{}'.format(project_name)

ml = discovery.build('ml', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
request = ml.projects().jobs().create(parent=project_id,
                                  body=body_fn())

try:
    response = request.execute()

    print('Job requested.')

    # The state returned will almost always be QUEUED.
    print('state : {}'.format(response['state']))

except errors.HttpError as err:
    # Something went wrong, print out some information.
    print('There was an error getting the prediction results.' +
      'Check the details:')
    print(err._get_reason())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this format for batch prediction:

```
{"inputs": {"b64": "/9j/4SurRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACgEPAAIAHAAAAhgEQAAIAAAAFAAAAjgEaAAUAAAABAAAAlAEbAAUAAAABAAAAnAEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAA1AAAApAEyAAIAAAAUA...}}
{"inputs": {"b64": "/9j/4SurRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACgEPAAIAAAAAAhgEQAAIAAAAFAAAAjgEaAAUAAAABAAAAlAEbAAUAAAABAAAAnAEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAA1AAAApAEyAAIAAAAUA...}}
```

In other words, the same format you used with `gcloud` to send online prediction requests.

The relationship between batch prediction, gcloud, and online prediction requests is as follows:

- gcloud's file format for both `local predict` and `predict` are the same as batch prediction
- The actually body of the request that is sent to online prediction when using gcloud converts each line of the file into the element of the "instances" array. So the actual body of the request (e.g., one you would send to the online prediction service if you weren't using gcloud, i.e. with curl, Python's `request` library, etc.) is `{"instances": [line1, line2, ...]}`

Comment: I tried to run the batch job from gcloud command, but it failed again with same error. I used the same format as you asked {"inputs": {"b64" : "b64 coded data"}}

Comment: did you try `gcloud ml-engine local predict` to begin? If you're still having problems, please reach out to cloudml-feedback@google.com, and provide a reference to this thread and job IDs.